# Simultaneusly connecting several webcams

Tags: linux, usb, webcam, v4l2

I have 4 webcams, plugged into a USB hub, that I would like to use with my computer. I can find out which devices are recognized by the computer with `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`. When I plug the entire hub in at once, none of the devices are recognized. If I connect each webcam sequentially, with ~10 seconds delay between each, they are all recognized and work as expected.

What would cause this issue? I've tested it on my laptop, which runs Ubuntu, and my Raspberry Pi, which runs Raspbian. Is there any way to get v4l to recognize all webcams when they're plugged in simultaneously?

p.s. The webcams in question are these incredibly cheap ones you can find listed as SQ11 on Alibaba.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the reason is caused by high power consumption by all camera. You can try to use USB HUB with an external power adapter.

Let's show `dmesg` log chunk when you connecting hub to your laptop